# RxJava - Just vs From

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm getting the same output when using `Observable.just` vs `Observable.from` in the following case:

```
 public void myfunc() {
 //swap out just for from here and i get the same results,why ?
        Observable.just(1,2,3).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d("","all done. oncompleted called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                Log.d("","here is my integer:"+integer.intValue());
            }
        });

    }
```

I thought `just` was just supposed to emit a single item and `from` was to emit items in some sort of list.  Whats the difference ? I also noted that `just` and `from` take only a limited amount of arguments. So `Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-2)` is ok but `Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,-3)` fails. Same goes for `from`, I have to wrap it in a list or array of sorts.  I'm just curious why they can't define unlimited arguments.

UPDATE: I experimented and saw that `just` does not take a array structure it just takes arguments. `from` takes a collection. so the following works for `from` but not for `just`:

```
 public Observable myfunc() {
    Integer[] myints = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
   return  Observable.just(myints).flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(final Integer integer) {
            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                    if(integer.intValue()>2){
                        subscriber.onNext(integer.intValue()>2);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

I am assuming this to be the clear difference then, correct ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The difference should be clearer when you look at the behaviour of each when you pass it an `Iterable` (for example a `List`):

`Observable.just(someList)` will give you 1 emission - a `List`.

`Observable.from(someList)` will give you N emissions - each item in the list.

The ability to pass multiple values to `just` is a convenience feature; the following are functionally the same:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable.from(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: in ver 2.1.0 there is no from(). It replaced with fromIterable() and some others, but the answer was correct. thanks.

Comment: Here https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/rxjava-operators-just-range-from-repeat/     Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) just takes 10 arguments and gives 10 emission. Why no body cares about this case?

Answer (score 10):

**Difference between `just()` and `from()`:**

All though `just()` and `from()` appears to be doing the same work, it differs in number of emissions.

`just()` – Makes only 1 emission. `Observable.just(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3})` makes one emission with Observer callback as `onNext(Integer[] integers)`

`fromArray()` – Makes N emissions. `Observable.fromArray(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3})` makes three emission with Observer callback as `onNext(Integer integer)`

Answer (score 2):

`from` works mostly with data structures (arrays and iterable) and futures, so the obtained `Observable` will emit single items from those data structures or futures.

`just` treats everything as item regardless it is an array item or integer item. The confusion around `just` is generated by the fact that there are a few `just` variants that can accept up to 10 arguments.

So in fact, you might interpret all those `just` variants like they emit, respectively, "just" one item, or "just" two items, "just" three items and so on...

Answer (score 1):

inRxJava **Just()** operator takes a list of arguments and converts the items into Observable items. It takes arguments between one to ten (But the official document says one to nine , may be it’s language specific).

Unlike just, **From()** creates an Observable from set of items using an Iterable, which means each item is emitted one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

We can just pass max 10 arguments in **just()** while **fromArray** have list type.

While internally **just()** calling **fromArray()**.

Check below RxJava Code for just 4 arguments.

```
 public static <T> Observable<T> just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(item1, "The first item is null");
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(item2, "The second item is null");
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(item3, "The third item is null");
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(item4, "The fourth item is null");

        return fromArray(item1, item2, item3, item4);
    }
```

Both are return same observable object.