# Different usages of just() operator in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

It is said that "just operator takes list and emit only once" in all documents i read on the web. However, there is such a usage in link https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/rxjava-operators-just-range-from-repeat/ :
Here it takes 10 argument and emits 10 times. Why nobody mention about it? I couldn't find any official docs about it. Can you clarify that?

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + integer);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see  `<T> Observable<T> just(T t1, T t2, T t3, T t4, T t5, T t6)` implementation and see, that it is using `from` operator:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> just(T t1, T t2, T t3, T t4, T t5, T t6) {
    return from((T[])new Object[] { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 });
}
```

Also, for better explanation see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820880/7530555) which @dglozano mentioned in comment.

Update: [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java) to Observable class in RxJava2, and [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java) to same class in RxJava 1.
Code snippet, which I wrote is from RxJava1

Comment: thanks in this case, the so link you gave is deficient. github links solved my question. there are 2 usages of just operator. one is the same with from operator and it is not mentioned anywhere else. second usage is different and mentioned in so answer link.

Comment: @metis np, sometime source code helps more then all answers in SO )